# how to adjust space in matrix from the right and left side?

Tags: amsmath, matrices

[image]I made a matrix with some elements in, and now I want to ajust space of right and left side to the first(last) element in matrix, but HOW?

```
\begin{displaymath}
P=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x & 0 & 0 \\
x & x & 0 \\
x & x & x \\
0 & x & x \\
0 & 0 & x \\
\end{matrix}
```

Comment: Is this relative to other elements in the `tikzpicture`, or things outside the `tikzpicture`? Do you want to add or remove space? If you can make a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228), that might be helpful in order to give you a good answer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you be more explicit?

Comment: `matrix` normally means the environment of that name from `amsmath` but you have tagged tikz-matrix do you intend to ask about that?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: The image doesn't really tell us what you've done. Can you show us some code? Is this a TikZ matrix, or an `amsmath` matrix?

Comment: What you want and need **depends heavily** on what you've done to realize it. Ti*k*Z? `amsmath`? Other methods? How have you come to see that the matrix need spacing? Perhaps some command from other packages? without a MWE (link in the first comment) nobody will be able not only to help, but to understand what to do to help you

Comment: Sorry, I added an example

Comment: so not tikz at all,  I will delete that tag, if you think it should be tagged as [tag:tikz-matrix] please edit the question to ask about tikz.

Comment: just get rid of the `\left[..\right]` and use `bmatrix` instead of `matrix` and better positioned brackets will be added.

Comment: Also—since, surely, you are using the `amsmath` package—replace `\begin{displaymath} ... \end{displaymath}` with `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}`, or just with `\[ ... \]`, which is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
P=
\left[\;
\begin{matrix}
x & 0 & 0 \\
x & x & 0 \\
x & x & x \\
0 & x & x \\
0 & 0 & x \\
\end{matrix}\;
\right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```